# Make images clickable to next image in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, image, hyperlink, clickable

I have a Previous/Next link on my site that lets me go thru the images with this code: 
`<a href="JavaScript:previousImage()">Previous</a> | <a href="JavaScript:nextImage()">Next</a> 
  <span id='num'></span>`

I have placed the images in the codes below. The Previous / Next links are working great but I would like to be able to click on the images itself to navigate to the next images: so click on 1.jpg then goes to 2.jpg so forth and once clicked on 5.jpg goes back to 1.jpg. Please advise, thanks in advance for your help. I am a beginner building my site blindly and any help is much appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var image = new Array("jpegs/1.jpg",
"jpegs/2.jpg",
"jpegs/3.jpg",
"jpegs/4.jpg",
"jpegs/5.jpg"
)

var imgNumber=1

var numberOfImg = image.length

function previousImage(){
  if(imgNumber > 1){
    imgNumber--
    }

  else{
    imgNumber = numberOfImg
    }

document.slideImage.src = image[imgNumber-1]

  }
function nextImage(){
  if(imgNumber < numberOfImg){
    imgNumber++
    }

  else{
    imgNumber = 1
    }

document.slideImage.src = image[imgNumber-1]

  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
document.slideImage.onclick = nextImage;
```

I would also suggest using event registration (also for the anchors):

```
document.slideImage.addEventListener('click', nextImage);
```

Comment: where would I put these code? Do you suggest putting both in or just the one below? Thanks

Comment: @RCook just the second one; put it in a script file that you include *after* the images are loaded

Comment: I put it there under the images: See below and the previous / next link stopped working and the images are not clicking to the next image either...please help, am i putting it on the wrong spot?        <script type="text/javascript">

var image = new Array("jpegs/1.jpg",
"jpegs/2.jpg",
"jpegs/3.jpg",
"jpegs/4.jpg",
"jpegs/5.jpg"
)
document.slideImage.addEventListener('click', nextImage);
var imgNumber=1

Comment: @RCook do you have a link to your site or something?  You're missing a semicolon and I image you're going to go through a *lot* of errors before you figure this out without my help

Comment: tried pasting in different places and it disabled the previous/next links so I put it at the bottom before the </script> which enabled the previous/next links but the images are still not clicking to the next image...please help @Explosion Pills thank u.

Comment: @RCook put the `click` in a `<script>` right before `</body>`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using `href="Javascript:function()"`, so to give you an idea of how to approach it...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    var n = 0;
    var src = ["jpegs/1.jpg", "jpegs/2.jpg", "jpegs/3.jpg", "jpegs/4.jpg", "jpegs/5.jpg"];
    var e = document.getElementById('slideImage');
    var prev = function() {
      n -= 1;
      if(n < 0) n = src.length - 1;
      e.setAttribute('src', src[n]);
    };        
    var next = function() {
      n += 1;
      if(n >= src.length) n = 0;
      e.setAttribute('src', src[n]);
    };
    e.onclick = next;
    document.getElementById('nextlink').onclick = next;
    document.getElementById('prevlink').onclick = prev;
  };
</script>
```

This method does not write variables to `window` (excluding `onload`) and only requires an `id` attribute.

Comment: this one didn't work for me. Disabled the previous / next link that was working and clicked image didn't go to the next image. Thanks though.